# Postgraphile StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

I use **Postgraphile** locally and it work very well.

[image]

I want to send a ****HttpClient** post requset** in my Application, but it does not work and I get this error:

**StatusCode: 405, ReasonPhrase: 'Method Not Allowed**

hier is my code:

```
 using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        string content = "query {accounts {nodes {id,name,street,postalcode,city}}}";
        var httpConent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:5000/graphiql", httpConent);
        var result = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 5 of your code snippet, you're submitting to the `/graphiql` URL (which is for the GraphiQL GUI), you should be submitting to `/graphql`.

In line 4 of your snippet, you are claiming the `content` variable is `application/json`, but it is in fact a GraphQL string. You should be submitting something like `{"query":"{__typename}"}` as `application/json`.

You do not appear to be issuing an `Accept: application/json` header.

I suggest you use the network debugging tools of your web browser to inspect exactly what the browser is doing when it runs the GraphQL query, and compare that with what you are attempting to do with your code. You might also refer to the GraphQL-over-HTTP specification: https://graphql.github.io/graphql-over-http/draft/